# How do I use the make sure that the table name is in lower case fir the query when the name is really in Upper case?

Tags: postgresql, function

How do I use the make sure that the table name is in lower case for the query when the name is really in Upper case?

```
- ERROR:  relation "public.billed" does not exist
- LINE 1: SELECT count(1) FROM public.BILLED
                             ^
- QUERY:  SELECT count(1) FROM public.BILLED
- CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function count_rows(text,text) line 7 at EXECUTE - - statement
```

Answer (score 0):

In postgres if you dont use double quotes the db assume lower case. So in your case you need to use

```
SELECT count(1) FROM public."BILLED"
```